# Parent class generic type based on a property generics

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to do the following implementation in Swift:

1. have a parent class that has 2 generic types: SuccessB and FailureB
2. the parent class will have a property (added via init) that has also 2 generic types SuccessA and FailureA
3. I need the SuccessB in the parent class to be the same type as in the property class and the same for the FailureB
4. so SuccessA == SuccessB and FailureA == FailureB

is it somehow possible?

```
protocol PropertyGenericsProtocol {
    associatedtype SuccessA
    associatedtype FailureA: Error
    
    func propertyMethod(completion: (Result<SuccessA, FailureA>) -> Void)
    func propertyMethodNoGenerics()
}

enum CustomError: Error {
    case invalid
}

class PropertyGenericsImpl: PropertyGenericsProtocol {
    typealias SuccessA = Bool
    typealias FailureB = CustomError
    
    func propertyMethod(completion: (Result<Bool, CustomError>) -> Void) {
        //
    }
    
    func propertyMethodNoGenerics() {
        
    }
}

class ParentClass<SuccessB, FailureB: Error> {
    var property: any PropertyGenericsProtocol
    
    init(property: any PropertyGenericsProtocol) {
        self.property = property
    }
    
    func main(completion: (Result<SuccessB, FailureB>) -> Void) {
        property.propertyMethodNoGenerics() // this is compiled
        
        // the compile throws an error here saying:
        // Member 'propertyMethod' cannot be used on value of type 
        // 'any PropertyGenericsProtocol'; consider using a generic constraint instead
        property.propertyMethod { result in
            // the type of the result should be simply SuccessB or FailureB here I guess in the desired state
            // result: Result<PropertyGenericsProtocol.SuccessA, PropertyGenericsProtocol.FailureA>
        }
    }
}
```

the reason why I'm doing all of this is that I'm subclassing Operation class (the parent class) that invokes method of the injected class (property protocol) and I want to be able to call completion within the Operation with a result type. If there's any other way how to do this, don't hesitate to let me know, I'll appreciate any help!

[the Operation API docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error message you could make the `ParentClass` generic to make use of the PropertyGenericsProtocol

```
class ParentClass<Property: PropertyGenericsProtocol> {
    var property: Property
    
    init(property: Property) {
        self.property = property
    }
    
    func main(completion: (Result<Property.SuccessA, Property.FailureA>) -> Void) {
        property.propertyMethodNoGenerics() 
        property.propertyMethod { result in
            
        }
    }
}
```